# Should signature of equals be equals(x: Any) or equals(x: AnyRef)

Tags: scala, autoboxing, language-interoperability

If the `equals` method in Scala is supposed to implement the original Java `boolean Object.equals(Object x)` method, I think it should be written `def equals(that: AnyRef): Boolean`.

IntelliJ generates instead `def equals(that: Any): Boolean`. Online I've also encountered examples using `Any` instead of `AnyRef`.

Should I define the type of the parameter `Any` or `AnyRef`?

I'm asking this because I would like to implement the method writing `this eq that`, but it doesn't work if the type of `that` is `Any`, I need to pattern-match first on `AnyRef` or a specific class. If I use `AnyRef` in my `equals` definition it clearly works but I'm not sure I'm doing the right thing in Scala.

Comment: What exactly is your use case? You shouldn't need to define your own `equals` in most cases.

Comment: I do, for unrelated reasons, and I need reference equality as noted above. Trying to use `this eq that` raised the need and question to clarify the exact definition of `equals`.

Comment: Isn't the default `equals` already by reference? Again, why you need to reimplement it yourself?

Comment: I need it `final`, I don't want that subclasses change the compare by reference.

Comment: Then the `asInstanceOf[AnyRef]` is the simplest solution. It is always safe, it will just trigger boxing on primitives. - In any case, I would just like to give you my humble opinion that it sounds like you have a bad design, but whatever.

Comment: I agree that the design is unusual, and it smells a bit. Currently I use `equals(x: Any)` and pattern matching to the specific class, instead of `asInstanceOf` as I prefer pattern matching to casting. However, the original question stays valid and, imho, not yet answered.

Comment: `Any` and `AnyRef` are both the same in the **JVM**. From a language point of view, they are different things, but in all runtimes you can safely cast from `Any` to `AnyRef`. I would recommend the cast in this case, the pattern match can be quite inefficient, and if you care that much for equality I assume you use it a lot.

Answer (score 3):

As noted, the default `equals` for `AnyRef` is reference equality (inherited from `java.lang.Object` and the signature of the `equals` method is `(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z` (i.e. Java bytecode for `java.lang.Object => Boolean` (technically it's `(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object) => Boolean` (the first `j.l.O` is `this`)).

The Scala compiler does some weird things in compiling `Any`/`AnyVal`/`AnyRef` in method arguments.  Consider:

```
class Foo {
  override def equals(that: Any): Boolean =
    that match {
      case r: AnyRef => this eq r
      case _ => false
    }
}
```

And use `:javap` in the REPL to inspect the bytecode:

```
  public boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=5, args_size=2
         0: aload_1
         1: astore_3
         2: aload_3
         3: instanceof    #4                  // class java/lang/Object
         6: ifeq          27
         9: aload_3
        10: astore        4
        12: aload_0
        13: aload         4
        15: if_acmpne     22
        18: iconst_1
        19: goto          23
        22: iconst_0
        23: istore_2
        24: goto          35
        27: goto          30
        30: iconst_0
        31: istore_2
        32: goto          35
        35: iload_2
        36: ireturn
```

It actually compiles to an `equals` method which takes only `Object`s (and then does an `instanceof`...).

This does bring up the question of what happens when we try to compare an `AnyRef` and an `AnyVal` for equality:

```
class Foo {
  override def equals(that: Any): Boolean =
    that match {
      case c: Char => c == 'M'
      case r: AnyRef => this eq r
      case _ => false
    }
}

object Bar {
  def cmpFooWithChar(f: Foo, c: Char): Boolean = f == c
}
```

In `Foo.equals`, `:javap` shows:

```
    3: instanceof    #18                 // class java/lang/Character
```

`java.lang.Character` being what `scala.Char` boxes to.

And in `Bar$`:

```
public boolean cmpFooWithChar($line15.$read$$iw$$iw$Foo, char);
  descriptor: (L$line15/$read$$iw$$iw$Foo;C)Z
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC
  Code:
    stack=2, locals=4, args_size=3
       0: aload_1
       1: iload_2
       2: invokestatic  #39                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToCharacter:(C)Ljava/lang/Character;
       5: astore_3
       6: dup
       7: ifnonnull     18
      10: pop
      11: aload_3
      12: ifnull        25
      15: goto          29
      18: aload_3
      19: invokevirtual #43                 // Method java/lang/Object.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      22: ifeq          29
      25: iconst_1
      26: goto          30
      29: iconst_0
      30: ireturn
```

Note how the compiler deals with the `==` operation:

- boxes the `Char` to a `Character`
- checks if either the boxed object or the `Foo` is `null`
- if both are non-null, it invokes the `equals` method

What sort of magic is happening?  Well,

```
def cmp(f: Foo, a: Any): Boolean = f == a
```

compiles to a signature of `(Foo, java.lang.Object) => Boolean`.  So, interestingly enough, does:

```
def cmp(f: Foo, v: AnyVal): Boolean
```

Yeah, you read that right: `AnyVal`, `AnyRef`, and `Any` as function argument types are all equivalent to `java.lang.Object` when compiled to bytecode and the compiler automatically boxes the `Int`.

It is mildly curious that the Scala compiler leaves in the `instanceof java.lang.Object` instruction, though I rather suspect that JIT will optimize away the check.  This does have an interesting effect: if we swap the `Char` and `AnyRef` cases in the second implementation of `Foo.equals`, the `Char` case becomes effectively dead code because it's after the `instanceof java.lang.Object`.  I suspect that the compiler's dead-code check, however, operates on the Scala types without regard to what the JVM types will be.

It would be really interesting to see the JS emitted by ScalaJS or the LLVM IR emitted by Scala Native for these examples.

Comment: If you're really paranoid about the superfluous `instanceof`, you could actually get away (at least on JVM-targeting Scala code) with `override def equals(that: Any): Boolean = this eq that.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]`: it would be 100% safe, though would probably trigger nearly any linter and you should be prepared to explain autoboxing and why a bare cast is safe in this (and probably only this) case to anybody who sees your code.